# How does AWS Batch override the container command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I have a docker image built with bazel via `py_image` rule and specifies a binary target. When supplying the image to AWS Batch, I can't seem to override the default command (which is the binary).

For example, `command = ["python"]` will give me a `main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: python` error.

Locally, if I do `docker run  --entrypoint python image:latest`, that does not throw an error.

This is suggesting that the container override is not using the equivalent of the `--entrypoint` option for `docker run`. If not, then what is AWS Batch doing?

For reference, the bazel config would look something like:

```
py_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.py"],
    data = [
        ":config_files",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//src/library/function",
    ],
)

py_image(
    name = "image",
    binary = ":main",
)
```

Comment: `entrypoint` and `command` are two separate things. You are talking about the two as if they are interchangeable, but they are not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile Also see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/demystifying-entrypoint-cmd-docker/

Comment: Ah gotcha. That makes sense. Sure enough `docker run image:latest python` yields the same error observed in AWS Batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` property of container override overrides the default command (`CMD`) of the Docker image, which *usually* is a list of arguments passed to the `ENTRYPOINT`. If however an `ENTRYPOINT` is not defined, then `CMD` is executed as is.

As per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskOverride.html#ECS-Type-TaskOverride-containerOverrides), it's currently not possible to override the entrypoint.

For more information on the differences between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, see [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)